# Pausing before drawing in Swing without using sleep

Tags: java, swing, sliding-tile-puzzle

I've made a game that is similar to 15 puzzle. The Node class stores the board state, its parent node and its depth. I am having a trouble with animating the solution of the problem. Since this method is invoked when a button is pressed when Thread.sleep is called the gui freezes until the state of the final node is displayed on the screen. How could I delay the animation for a certain period between the transition from one state to another?

```
public void animateSolution(Node node)
{
    Stack<Node> solution = new Stack<>();

    while (node != null)
    {
        solution.push(node);
        node = node.getParent();
    }

    solution.pop();

    while (!solution.isEmpty())
    {
        Node current = solution.pop();

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(750);

        }
        catch (InterruptedException ie)
        {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }

        moveBuilder(current);
    }

}
```

Comment: Use the [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) Luke!

Comment: @Sergiy Medvynskyy I tried but i had no success with it.

Comment: So please provide a short runnable example ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org)), so we can see what you do, debug your code and then we possible can suggest you a solution.